# Ordenar array php

Tags: php, array, classificação

Tenho um `array`, em que os valores são `arrays`.

Como posso **ordenar o primeiro** `array`, de acordo **com um valor que está no segundo** `array`?

**Exemplo:**

```
array(array(id=>5), array(id=>2), array(id=>1), array(id=>3));
```

**O pretendido é:**

```
array(array(id=>1), array(id=>2), array(id=>3), array(id=>5));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adaptado desta [excelente resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value) no SOen:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'id'=>5,
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>2,
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>1,
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>3,
    )
);
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['id'] - $b['id'];
});
print_r($array); // Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 5 ) )
```

Com PHP 7 podemos usar o [spaceship operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['id'] <=> $b['id'];
});
```

Comment: excelente implementação do spaceship operator.

Comment: Obgado @AllanAndrade, na realidade foi adaptado de uma resposta no SOen, coloquei o link na resposta

Comment: Não consigo o mesmo esquema para ordenar por data, ou seja, onde no array acima tenho números inteiros, ter um datetime (2016-08-25 19:57:28).
Existe alguma forma simples de resolver esta situação?