# Como ordenar um foreach por um valor da array?

Tags: php

Boa tarde galera, estou fazendo um ranking com 10 pessoas, está exibindo os 10, porém eu queria exibir na ordem decrescente através do value Score

```
<article class="rank">
<h2>Ranking de Jogadores Online</h2>
<?php
    if(!is_array($aTotalPlayers) || count($aTotalPlayers) == 0){
    echo '<br /><i>No players online!</i>';
  } else {
  ?>
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:600px;" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><b>#</b></td>
        <td><b>Nickname</b></td>
        <td><b>Score</b></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($aTotalPlayers as $id => $value){
        if($i >= 10){
            break;
        }
        $i++;
  ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($value['Nickname']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['Score']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
    }
        echo '</table>';
    }

  ?>
```

Ou seja, teria que exibir os 10 que tem mais score na ordem decrescente, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Seria isso [Ordenar array php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147939/91) ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 1):

Duas maneiras de resolver o problema:

1. na consulta SQL, coloque no final da sua consulta `order by Score DESC`.
2. ordene o seu array, pegando a coleção antes do laço: `asort()` é decrescente, `sort()` é crescente: `asort($aTotalPlayers)`;